# Howto select an where - if - in with Kohana ORM?

Tags: php, mysql, orm, kohana

Im trying to do this in with Kohana ORM but have no idea how to do that:

```
SELECT t.name
FROM t
WHERE IF(t.s1_id = 1, t.s2_id IN (2,3,4), t.s1_id IN (2,3,4))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked with this myself but with floww's transformation, this should do the trick

```
$model = ORM::factory('t')->and_where_open()
    ->where('s1_id', '=', '1')
    ->where('s2_id', 'IN', array(2,3,4))
    ->and_where_close()
    ->or_where('s1_id', 'IN', array(2, 3, 4));
```

If you expect one result, use `$model->find()` now and you can access the name via `$model->name`.

If you expect multiple results, use `$model->find_all()` and iterate over it, getting all the `->name`s

---

As you can see in the [API browser](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/ORM), ORM doesn't support `IF` statements. If you don't want a hardcoded solution like the one posted, I think you'd have to add this functionality yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.name FROM t WHERE (t.s1_id = 1 and t.s2_id IN (2,3,4) ) or ( t.s1_id IN (2,3,4) )
```